# Using find to search for files containing a word

Tags: find

I want to use the find command to find all files on the system that have the word fsck.

I tried

```
find / -iname fsck
```

and it started to search files but everything was permission denied.  When I try executing with `sudo` the command line just seems to hang.

Am I on the right track here?  I am really stumped as to how to do this..

Comment: If the files contain the word, then what you want is `grep -R`, but even so, you should exclude: `/proc`, `/sys`, `/run` from the search.

Comment: There are always a lot of "permission denied" outputs cluttering the results.  What I usually do is to follow the command with `2>/dev/null`, which causes them to be ignored.  For example,  `find / -iname '*fsck*' 2>/dev/null`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to make sure it was a typo, I see your command has fckd instead of fsck.

Typically how I would do it is:

```
find / -iname '*fsck*'
```

I wouldn't be surprised if the command took quite a while to complete but it should show results as it sees them.

The main thing is, you need the pattern to be a glob like you'd use with 'ls'.

Putting the pattern in single quotes makes it so that your shell doesn't try to expand *fsck* into a list of matching files in your current directory prior to running the find command.  For example, if you had no files that matched *fsck* in your current directory the command run would end up being:

```
find / -iname
```

Or if you had 3 files [ fsck.a fsck.b fsck.c ] in your current directory the command run would end up being

```
find / -iname fsck.a fsck.b fsck.c
```

By escaping or quoting the *fsck* the command ends up as you would expect it:

```
find / -iname *fsck*
```

I believe you can also escape the *'s with \*fsck\*.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Or, for text **within** files as muru pointed out, but I d̶o̶n̶'̶t̶  didn't (thanks) have reputation points to followup.

`grep -sinIR fsck *` for **g**lobaly search **r**egular **e**xpression and **p**rint   --**s**upressing errors, **i**gnoring case, returning line **n**umbers, **I**gnore binary files, and do it **R**ecursively,  ***** all files in the directory

As sparhawk pointed out `locate` is a handy tool.  `locate -i nAmE` to ignore case, `-A` for mutiple search terms, e.g., `locate -iA fsck txt` which will return all files inclusive of `fsck` and `txt` in the name *with an updated database*.

Answer (score 1):

To find files that *contain* fsck, you need to use wildcards.

```
find / -iname '*fsck*'
```

You are correct that sudo is required. It was "hanging" because it needs to traverse your entire file system, which takes a long time. Alternatively, I'd recommend using `locate`, which uses a pre-compiled index, and is hence much quicker. This index is usually updated regularly by a cronjob, but you can ensure that it is up to date with

```
sudo updatedb
```

Then you can search for your file with

```
sudo locate fsck
```